# Taking several slices from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Say I'd like to take the ith column along with every column from the yth column to last column.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(50).reshape(5,10)
```

Now, say I'd like to take the 2nd column, along with all columns from #7 through the last.

I can take several slices like so:

```
a[:,[2,4,8]]
```

However, what is the correct way to do the following?:

```
a[:,[1,6:]]
```

This approach currently results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate multiple multiple slices that can be then applied along the second axis:

```
a[:, np.r_[1, 6:a.shape[1]]]
```

Quick check:

```
np.allclose(a[:, np.r_[1, 6:a.shape[1]]],  a[:, [1,6,7,8,9]])
# True
```